# Can I timestamp a .NET assembly using local computer time?

Tags: timestamp, code-signing, digital-certificate, authenticode, code-signing-certificate

I use the following UL for timestamp: http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll

But the internet goes off on rare occasions and the assembly needs to be compiled and certified and timestamped, so is there any way to timestamp an assembly using the computer's clock time on which it is being timestamped and code-signed/certified instead of using a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. the purpose of digital timestamping is to certify the time, at which your signature is made. It's the third-party that certifies the time, so you can't do this yourself.